# Using $(this) at a method inside another method in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, each, selector

So, I'm trying to use the 'this' selector in a method inside another method, example:

```
$('form').submit(function(event){
   $('input').each(function(){
       if($(this).val().length < 2){
           $(this).addClass('error');
           event.preventDefault(); 
       }
   });
});
```

When I made that, I thought it would admit 'this' as each input, but no, the 'this' selector are associated to the form. I know that because the result is:

```
<form class="error" action="lorem.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Lorem Ipsum" name="example">
</form>
```

That's only an example to illustrate that when I submit a form, the class 'error' goes to the 'form' tag.

I want to know how can I call each 'input' inside the 'each' method, since 'this' seems not to work.

I hope I made my point here, if someone needs more explanation just tell me.

Thank you very much!

Comment: that code works fine http://jsfiddle.net/5rq3w7h6/1/

Comment: Have you tried to give the input a `val=""` attribute, maybe that's why it won't work? or are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Shame on me, thank you, the problem wasn't the concept but the execution.

Comment: @Paul no, there's no error at console, I'm just stupid hahah. But thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send index, and element to your function.

```
$('form').submit(function(event){
   $('input').each(function(index, element){
       if($(element).val().length < 2){
           $(element).addClass('error');
           event.preventDefault(); 
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: No you do not, index and element in 'each(function(index,element))' are optional as verified by Sgnl link

Comment: @Ohohorion it's optional but it's more explicit to use those references than to rely on what 'this' refers to.

Comment: @user2368033 I didn't knew that parameters, thank you!

Comment: @Sgnl I do agree you on that point. It is better practice to use index and element than 'this'.